# self.array = nums: what is time complexity for assignment of lists in python?

Tags: python, arrays

I was solving Dot Product of Two Sparse Vectors (*Given two sparse vectors, compute their dot product.*) and I got confused about time complexity.

For solution:

```
class SparseVector:
    def __init__(self, nums):
        self.array = nums

    def dotProduct(self, vec):
        result = 0
        for num1, num2 in zip(self.array, vec.array):
            result += num1 * num2
        return result
```

it says in answer that

*Time complexity: `O(n)` for both constructing the sparse vector and calculating the dot product.*

Why time complexity of `__init__` is `O(n)`? I thought that `self.array = nums` is simple assignment like `list_1 = list_2` and should has time complexity `O(1)`.

Comment: seems that calculation is included in that time complexity, also probably by construction is meant instantiation and stuff

Comment: assignment is always constant time in Python. "Why does time complexity for constructing the sparse vector is O(n)? " What does that even mean? Please understand, questions must be self-contained. This site isn't for speculation about what some other, unspecified source is telling you. Your link requires a login.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I removed link. My question is simple: what time complexity of `__init__`?

Comment: It is constant time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, the assignment is O(1).  Assignment in Python never does any copying unless you explicitly make a copy, you just end up with two references to the same object.  Doesn't matter how large the object is.

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, time complexity is O(n*m). Where n and m are the sizes of the arrays.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).